# Open a Blender 3.5 file in Blender 3.4 and earlier

Tags: blend-files, versions

Is there any way to open a blend file made in Blender 3.5 in older versions of Blender? I'd go the FBX route, but I want to preserve the rig.

Answer (score 1):

If simply opening does not work(it does when I try it), you could try appending from the file:

[image]

It's generally not a very good idea to do this as this might corrupt your data and it is hard to tell what features might stop working. You might have unexpected issues in the future if the project you are working on is big and complex. It is better to remove the obstacles stopping you from using the newer version.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I want to use the new version but my Mac can't update to 10.15 which is required.

Comment: Blender stores data in data blocks which make it safe to open the file in an older version of Blender. Yes, the project might stop working, because e.g. some Geometry Nodes will not be recognized, but from my experience you can do something in an older version just because an extension works there, save the file, open it again in the newer version and the file **is not** corrupted. Which is pretty rare for software.

Comment: I have had problems even when opening files with newer versions. That happened when Color Mix node was changed for example, and plenty of other times. It's not a very good idea to change versions in the middle of a project in any case. Even if it's fixable, it's extra work. It's better to avoid if possible.

Comment: Appending doesn't seem to work for me. Everytime I try to append something, whether it be a scene, object, or mesh. Blender crashes everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can start to append the whole "scene", first. If you still have problems, you can append individual objects or collections one by one, and check if all works. But there's no guarantee all will work.